# 2 Unequal strings are returned with true value on == as well as a.compare(b)

Tags: c++, string, class, binary-search-tree, equals

I'm making a BST & AVL tree working on string keys.
In the main , I've not added the "600" key but on finding it shows "600" found.

I tried debugging using gdb & found out that on 2 unequal strings == gave a true value passed my if clause.

I also tried using compare() function of string class, still the same problem.
 Please Help !

This is my `findNode` function:

```
template<class NodeType>
NodeType* Tree<NodeType>::findNode(string key, NodeType* node)
{
    if ( node == NULL )
        return NULL;
    else if ( node->Key() == key )
        return node;
    else if ( key < node->Key() )
        findNode(key, node->Left());
    else if ( key > node->Key() )
        findNode(key, node->Right());
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

Here is the link to all of the code 
https://github.com/tshrjn/ADSA/blob/master/bst.cpp

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here. No one wants to go through hundreds of lines of code looking for your errors.

Comment: Don't post links to code, instead copy-paste the ***relevant*** parts of the code inside the actual question body. Or even better, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your `findNode` method, you're missing `return` on the recursive calls to `findNode(...left...)` and `findNode(...right...)`:

```
template<class NodeType>
NodeType* Tree<NodeType>::findNode(string key, NodeType* node)
{
    if ( node == NULL )
        return NULL;
    else if ( node->Key() == key )
        return node;
    else if ( key < node->Key() )
        return findNode(key, node->Left());
    else if ( key > node->Key() )
        return findNode(key, node->Right());
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

Your implementation returned garbage in these cases (which are most cases).

---

If you compiled with the `-Wall`flag, then the compiler would have **found this error for you**.

Btw, there are several more errors found by this flag, you might want to check it out.